# python oops conditional statements in a class

Tags: python, class, oop

*Create a class called boat. In the__init__(), allow the user to specify the following attributes: price, speed, fuel, mileage. If the price is greater than 100,000, set the tax to be 20%. Otherwise set the tax to be 18%.*

**How do I do a conditional in my class, saying, if price > 100,000 then tax = 20%?**

```
Here's my code so far:

class boat(object):
    def __init__(self, price, speed, fuel, mileage, tax):
        self.price = price
        self.speed = speed
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.tax = tax
```

Comment: Think of a class as a function. You can have a class do things that a function would do, such as use if statements and loops.

Comment: @Rory Perro: If you like my answer, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by:

```
class boat(object):
    def __init__(self, price, speed, fuel, mileage):
        if price > 100000:
            self.price = price* 1.20
        else:
            self.price = price* 1.18
        self.speed = speed
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.tax = tax
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class boat(object):
    def __init__(self, price, speed, fuel, mileage):
        self.price = price
        if price > 100000:
            self.tax = 0.2
        else:
            self.tax = 0.18
        self.speed = speed
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.mileage = mileage
```

You can change the 0.2 to 1.2, for example, seeming as we are adding on tax. However I will leave that up to you as I assume that this is only a small snippet of your code so you can make the choice of what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class boat:
    def __init__(self, price, speed, fuel, mileage):
        self.price = price
        if price > 100000:
            self.tax = 0.2
        else:
            self.tax = 0.18
        self.speed = speed
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.price+=self.tax
```

As there is a conditional in the question, we can use conditional in the class itself so that all the objects instantiated from the class will follow the conditional and gets updated.